# What is known about A’ani, the ancient Egyptian God of Equilibrium?

Tags: egyptian

[Wikipedia’s article on Thoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoth) states that A’ani is a form of Thoth, which is consistent with what I know about Thoth, although much of the information I'm working with comes through the hermeticism.

Wikipedia’s citation for A’ani comes from Budge’s [*Hieroglyphic Dictionary*](https://archive.org/details/egyptianhierogly01budguoft), but the work dates from 1920, so I’m assuming there may be more recent scholarship.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found much. All I have found is that A'an resides in Duat(the Underworld/realm of the dead). As the god of equilibrium, he took the form of an ape. He recorded the weighing of the hearts of the dead as he was a scibe.

It is plausible that he, as A'an, not Ibis/Thoth, took part in the Three Epic Battles.
[Thoth’s role within these battles was to ensure neither side won a complete victory, which would disrupt the balance of the universe. To prevent this from happening, Thoth would heal the wounds of the combatants.](http://kingtutone.com/gods/thoth/)

Although Thoth, the god of knowledge, is credited, it is likely to be A'an, the god of equilibrium, that participated to keep *balance of the universe.*

Comment: Just to keep us all on our toes, Egyptians would actually hail gods as "polyonymous" -- having many names.

Answer (score -1):

According to Stuart R. Kaplan, Lady Frieda Harris under the guidance of Aleister Crowley described a tarot card that mentioned a cynocephalus ape, which I understand to be A'ani, and his relation to Thoth as, "THE MAGICIAN OR JUGGLER. Mercury, who is Wisdom. Will and Word, by whom the world is created, symbolises the fluidic basis of all transmission of activity. Behind him and through him is the Ape, Hanuman, which is a Hindu conception. The Egyptian counterpart, Thoth, is also always followed by the Cynocephalus Ape".
Lady Harris later wrote this second description of the card, "THE MAGICIAN OR JUGGLER. Mercury. Beth. He is Mercury, the messenger of God, and juggles with the four symbols of the elements, and the papyrus or Word, the pen or Will, the wand or Wisdom. He represents the creative force in action. As Thoth in Egyptian tradition, his attendant and shadow is the Cynocephalus Ape".
Kaplan also notes that further information on the history and symbolism of Tarot can be found in The Encyclopedia of Tarot published by U.S. Games Systems, Inc.
I hope this helps.